# String from hex without encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have a string that contains hex values, something like:
"1BB3AE3E".

Now I would like to convert this to a string (expected result "≥Æ>") of exactly that byte representation (so written to a file, and opened with hex viewer would show "1BB3AE3E")

This is something like Ruby's

```
['1BB3AE3E'].pack('H*')
```

I have tried creating Buffer.toString, String.fromCharCode, but it didn't work as I expected. The closes I got to the result was with

```
var input = "1BB3AE3E"
var buffer = new Buffer(input, "hex")
var result = buffer.toString("binary")
```

and it resulted with a file containing "³®>" for which hex is: 1B **C2** B3 **C2** AE 3E.
Where those **C2** are coming from? How can I make it work?

I've also tried

```
var hexes = this.match(/.{1,2}/g) || [];
var back = "";
for(j = 0; j< hexes.length; j++) {
    back += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hexes[j], 16));
}
```

but to no vain. The effect is as above.

Comment: I have managed to achieve what I want by creating a stream `wstream = fs.createWriteStream("file.txt"); wstream.write(buff); wstream.end()` but this is async operation and requires me to store buffer to a file and read it from there again. Seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
//var result= parseInt(buffer, 16).toString(2)
  var result= parseInt(input, 16).toString(2)
```

`Output:"11011101100111010111000111110"`

also see:
https://gist.github.com/faisalman/4213592

Comment: please check now,don't have node on my pc right now..but this works on js

Answer (score 0):

For do a good code you should be hexDecode and the protoype and fromCharCode and parseInt, you can do for examples:

```
String.prototype.hexDecode = function(){
    var j;
    var hexes = this.match(/.{1,4}/g) || [];
    var back = "";
    for(j = 0; j<hexes.length; j++) {
        back += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hexes[j], 16));
    }

    return back;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that already and unfortunately it doesn't work. It basically provides same effect as my code (only when you do this.match(/.{1,2}/g) ).